# Form field: Adding new <inputs> to the inside of a <form> via Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to add new fields via a button into my form. However, it adds it to the outside of the form. Any ideas on what to edit to accomplish this? Thanks.

My HTML:

```
<div id="page">

<h1>Quick Order</h1>
<div id="dynamicInput">
<form method="post" name="QuickOrderMulti">

<input type="hidden" name="formName" value="dmiformQuickOrderMulti">

  <p>Product #  <input type='Text' name="ProductNumber" title="Enter Product #"></p>
  <p>Product #  <input type='Text' name="ProductNumber" title="Enter Product #"></p>


<input type="submit" value="Add"><input type="button" value="Add another text input"     onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">

</form>
</div>
</div> <!-- page -->
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
var limit = 3;
function addInput(dynamicInput){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Product # " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text'     name='ProductNumber[]'>";
          document.getElementById(dynamicInput).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Wanna give us an update or choose a correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You're appending to the DIV surrounding the form thus the fields won't be inside the child form.

Either put the form around your "dynamicInput" div... or insert inside the form instead.

**Option A:**

```
<form method="post" name="QuickOrderMulti">
  <div id="dynamicInput">
  ...
  </div>
</form>
```

**Option B:**

```
<div id="dynamicInput">
  <form method="post" name="QuickOrderMulti" id="QuickOrderMulti">
  ...
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  ...
  document.getElementById('QuickOrderMulti').appendChild(newdiv);
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the input to the div, not the form. Just give the form an id and add the input fields to that.

```
document.getElementById("formId").innerHTML = "Product # " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text'     name='ProductNumber[]'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
var limit = 3;
function addInput(dynamicInput){
 if (counter == limit)  {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
 }
 else {
 var parent = document.getElementById('myform')
 var element = null;
 try { // IE
 element = document.createElement('<input type="text" name="ProductNumber[]">');
 } 
 catch (e) { // W3C
 element = document.createElement("input");
 element.setAttribute("type", "text");
 element.setAttribute("name", "ProductNumber[]");
  }
 parent.appendChild("Product # " + (counter + 1) + element);
 counter++;
  }
}
 </script>
```